# Keep play application running after putty terminal closed

Tags: session, playframework, terminal, putty, playframework-2.3

How to keep play application running after putty terminal closed?

After deploying play application in to server, I ssh'ed into server with putty terminal and ran the play application.

However, once I close the putty terminal, play application no longer accepts http requests from client. 
To start the play application I used following command;

```
./{myplayapp}/bin/{executable} -Dhttp.port=8000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use screen to start your application. view existing screens with "screen -ls" and switch between them with "screen -r"
http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/screen

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend `nohup`:

```
nohup ./script -Dhttp.port=8000 &
```

It will create `nohup.out` file with all the logs. If you want to quit it, grep `RUNNING_PID` and `sudo kill` it.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer! Using **&** symbol run the process in background so that even if putty terminal is closed, process not terminated.

```
./{myplayapp}/bin/{executable} -Dhttp.port=8000 > app.out &
```

Comment: screen (see answer above) is a nicer solution.  It's a terminal you can jump in and out of, detach from, share with others.  It's perfect for things like this.

Comment: Agreed. Screen is the best solution. "&" doesn't seem to work reliably