# How to exit putty without killing powershell process?

Tags: node.js, powershell, server, putty, remote-server

I am hosting a discord bot on a linux server using powershell. But whenever I exit putty it kills the powershell process. How do I keep it running?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is not really a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). And it has been asked zillion times already. For example https://stackoverflow.com/q/27365021/850848

Answer (score 0):

On the linux side, use `&` to run the process in the background, and the `nohup` command to keep running when your user exits a shell (putty session):

```sh
# Run your command 
[user@server ~]$ nohup pwsh -Command 'Do-Thing -Foo a -Bar b' &

# Or run a script
[user@server ~]$ nohup pwsh -File /path/to/script.ps1 &
```

It will show up as a job in `jobs`, but only until you disconnect:

```sh
[user@server ~]$ jobs
[1]+  Running         nohup pwsh -Command 'Sleep -100' &

# bring the job to the foreground and kill it, for example
[user@server ~]$ fg 1
[user@server ~]$ ^C
```

Once you disconnect, the job will run on its own. Use `ps` to find the running process and kill it if needed:

```sh
[user@server ~]$ ps -e | grep pwsh
30975 ?        00:00:01 pwsh

[user@server ~]$ kill 30975
```

---

If you want something more robust (like auto-restart if crashed), you can set it up to [run as a service](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236084/how-do-i-create-a-service-for-a-shell-script-so-i-can-start-and-stop-it-like-a-d), but the steps for that can vary between flavors of linux.

Comment: Consider posting your answer to some of the many duplicate questions instead.

Answer (score -1):

In powershell use:

```
powershell -noExit "cf ssh app_name"
```

It is possible to set a powershell function to shorten it:

```
function psne { powershell -NoExit $args[0]}
```

Then run

```
psne "cf ssh app_name"
```